# CSS Grid Layout Module - Is the final specification out & where to find it?

Tags: css

Is this grid layout specification finalized by W3C: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/ ?

Answer (score 1):

The World Wide Web Consortium oversees the drafting and approval of CSS specifications. You can find out if a specification has been finalized and find draft and final specifications at the W3C website:

https://www.w3.org/

This appears to be the latest version of the Grid Layout specification:

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/